# do a task based on multiple onItemSelectedListeners

Tags: android, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

i am using three spinners to get input from the user, and based on this information i will then graph some data. however i cannot seem to figure out how to do this. i have the following code (extract to show the important bits):

```
final GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
Spinner selectGraphSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.graphSpinner);
Spinner selectUserSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.userSpinner);
Spinner selectTimeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.timeSpinner);
    String[] items = new String[]{"Please Select a User", "04950f4ae53f80", "another user"};

    // Create ArrayAdapters for Spinners
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> selectGraphAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.Graphs,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
ArrayAdapter<String> userSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinTimeAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.TimeIncrements,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);  
selectGraphSpinner.setAdapter(selectGraphAdapter);
selectUserSpinner.setAdapter(userSpinnerAdapter);
selectTimeSpinner.setAdapter(spinTimeAdapter);
```

the onItemSelectedListeners x 3 repeat for other spinner:

```
selectUserSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            itemOne = parent.getItemAtPosition(0).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

the graphing logic so far:

```
while (itemOne != null) {
        if (itemOne.equalsIgnoreCase("04950f4ae53f80")) {
            if (itemTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("Estimated vs Actual Time")) {
                if (itemThree.equalsIgnoreCase("Day")) {
                    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(getData(Data, "Day"));

                    graph.addSeries(series);

                } else {

                }
            } else {

            }

        } else {

        }
    }
```

i know that the graph works as i tried with one spinner, but cant figure out why the listeners are not saving the variables (which i declared global - static String itemOne, etc) 
thanks
edit: the spinners contain multiple strings with a different initial one, but the used ones are mentioned,

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by saving the clicked items from each spinner to a global function/variable. this then allowed me to run a logic check which would return true or false depending on the case. i then put the graphing method within the listeners such that it would be implemented if the logic check returned true